# java update properties file run time

Tags: java

i am writing standalone java app for production monitoring. once it starts running the api is configured for default values which is set in .properties file. in running state the api's configuration can be changed and the .properties file should be updated accordingly. is there a way to achieve this ? or are there any other approaches to implement this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Java Properties class ([api here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)) specifies "load" and "store" methods which should do exactly that.  Use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to specify the file to save it into.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a very simple approach based on the [java.util.Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class which has indeed a [load](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) and [store](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) methods that you can use in conjunction with a FileInputStream and FileOutputStream:

But actually, I'd recommend to use an existing configuration library like [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) (amongst others). Check the [Properties Howto](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html) to see how to load, save and automatically reload a properties file using its API.

Answer (score 6):

I completely agree that Apache Commons Configuration API is really good choice.

This example update properties at runtime

```
File propertiesFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());        
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(propertiesFile);           
config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
config.save();
```

From the post [how to update properties file in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-io/how-to-update-properties-file-in-java.html)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

java.util.Properties doesn't provide runtime reloading out-of-the-box as far as I know.
[Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) provides support for reloading configuration at runtime. The reload strategy can be configured by [setting a ReloadingStrategy on the PropertiesConfiguration object](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#Automatic_Reloading). It also offers various other useful utilities for making your application configurable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `load` and `store` method of the `Properties` class, you can also use the Apache Commons Configuration library, which provides functions to easily manipulate configuration files (and not only .properties files).

Answer (score 0):

Apache common configuration API provided different strategies to reload property files at run time. FileChangedReloadingStrategy is one of them. Refer this [link](http://ourownjava.com/java/how-to-reload-property-file-in-java-at-runtime/) to see an example for property file reloading at run time using FileChangedReloadingStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// Write in property file at runtime

```
public void setValue(String key, String value) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
     String path = directoryPath+ "/src/test/resources/runTime.properties";
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        final FileInputStream configStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        props.load(configStream);
        configStream.close();
        props.setProperty(key, value);
        final FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
        props.store(output, "");
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

// Read same file

```
 public String getValue(String key) {
        String value = null;
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            File f = new File(directoryPath+"/src/test/resources/runTime.properties");
            if (f.exists()) {
                prop.load(new FileInputStream(f));
                value = prop.getProperty(key);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read from runTime.properties");
        }
        return value;
    }
```