# Update configuration value dynamically without restarting server/JVM

Tags: java

I know a couple of approaches for doing this but want to know if I am missing any others.

1. Store configuration values in DB and have a different service which will reload configuration values from DB.
2. Managed bean and update it using Jconsole.

Any other?

Comment: What’s wrong with the two you have?

Comment: Too many to mention, but it's not clear which ones would be preferable.

Comment: One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659642/java-update-properties-file-run-time

Comment: @PeterLawrey You mind mentioning at least few prevalent ones

Comment: You could also send a message to the application, using, e.g., `REST`. This question is very broad.

Comment: Followin up on KevinO: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/ distributed configuration is one of the many roads to travel